# Android. How to adjust height and width of a custom component using XML attributes?

Tags: android, xml, components, height, width

Is there any way to adjust height and width of a custom component using XML attributes?

For example, I created a component and its layout.

Here is XML layout of the component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a simple class that inflates this layout:

```
public class CustomComponent extends LinearLayout
{
    public CustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.custom_component, null);
        addView(view);
    }
}
```

The custom component is used in layout of some activity that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <view
        class = "com.tests.CustomComponent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The component is meant to be stretched to full size of a screen (that's why its layout parameters set to "fill_parent") but that is never happen.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as your `CustomComponent` extends `LinearLayout`, you just need to inflate the layout directly into it (parsing `this` as the ViewGroup, as your `CustomComponent` will be the holding view):

```
public class CustomComponent extends LinearLayout
{
    public CustomComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate( context, R.layout.custom_component, this );
    }
}
```

If that doens't work, try supplying only the constructor that takes a context:

```
public class CustomComponent extends LinearLayout
{
    public CustomComponent(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        inflate( context, R.layout.custom_component, this );
    }
}
```

Comment: first solution is good , but second is not possible because when you will add view in XML layout it will alwats search for constructor (context, AttributeSet)

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer you've made my day. The first solution works.